# How to install the RHIDE C++ IDE in OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, development, unix, ide

I'm looking to mimic the environment of the classic Turbo C++ compiler from the DOS days on Mac OS X. I have used DOSBox with actual Turbo C++ installed in the virtual drive, but I'm just experimenting with other options.

I've been writing basic C++ programs using `nano` and compiling them with `g++`, but I'm looking for something more integrated and TC++-like.

I found [RHIDE](http://www.rhide.com/), which appears to be a clone of the Turbo C++ IDE and is available for both DOS and Linux.

[image: RHIDE]

However, I'm not sure which package I should be downloading and where I should be installing it. The binary download options are:

- binaries for DJGPP (zip)
- binaries for GNU/Linux SuSE 8.0 (rpm)
- binaries for CYGWIN (tar.gz)
- binaries for GNU/Linux (debian/woody) (deb)

I figured `rpm` and `deb` options are out, but the `tar.gz` seems to be CYGWIN-based, leaving `zip` as the only option, but even that's for Windows. Which one should I get? Where should I extract it? How should I run it?

I'm running Mavericks 10.9.1.

Comment: Try Xcode as the simplest to setup and you have already installed it to get the complier. If that is not good enough then you can explain what is missing to find a better IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked out the source code. The code is not not suitable for Mac OS.

```
configure: error: i386-apple-darwin13.0.0 is not supported (yet). Sorry.
```

Comment: oh, darn it. I guess it'll have to be TC++ under DOSBox then! Or RHIDE under DOSBox, but I don't know what I'm achieving here. :-/

Comment: I guess you're best of utilizing vim or emacs. Regarding vim I can tell you there are millions of ways to make it work like a fully loaded IDE, including code completion, build-routines et cetera. You can start off from scratch, load preconfigured dotfiles and use vim package managers like Vundle. Also, these things are actively maintained!

Comment: Vi(m) scares me. But I guess I have to face my fears sometime! Thanks!